# Fade in/out the hover for gallery box

Tags: jquery, css

Hello and sorry for asking simple things! I am a jQuery noob and even tough I researched a lot I did not manage to make this simple effect work.

I want child to be faded in on parent hover and fade out on mouseout.

My other problem is that all the divs have the same class and if I show/hide childrens on hover the effect applies for all the other divs as well and that is really bad... I need a way to make jquery understand wich element is hovered even tough all of them have the same class.

I am not sure how well I explained this but I made a quick jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6nBBZ/

and here is my jquery:

```
$(".container").mouseover(function() {
$("a").fadeIn("slow");
});
$(".container").mouseout(function() {
$("a").fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out my new updated answer..with img tags

Answer (score 4):

You need to study jQuery's [DOM traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/), these will help you in this kind of situations where you need to find elements relative to other elments, in your case you want to use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to select descendants of the hovered element.

Also, instead of `mouseover` you should use `mouseenter` to handle the hover event so the code only runs once when the mouse enters the element, personally I prefer to use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) with two 
function arguments to handle `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` respectively:

```
$(".container").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("a").stop().fadeIn("slow");
},function(){
    $(this).find("a").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nBBZ/1/)**

Also note that you need to remove your CSS rule and let jQuery handle the display of the elements

Comment: I really appreciate the help, it's also good to know what I need to study.

Comment: @user1831609 Glad to help. I you feel this answer was helpful and resolved your issue please consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark next to it

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".container").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.hover').fadeIn(500);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.hover').fadeOut(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/LyjB9/2/

Comment: Thank you! However there is no fade in/fade out effect

Comment: Just put fadeOut(500) ,fadeIn(500) there. Anyway I have updated my fiddle.Check it.

Comment: I did put the parameters when I first tried the fiddle and I also rechecked it but for some reason it's still not working.

Comment: you have to remove this style from your css,
 
.container:hover > a {
    display:block;
}

it is the same as show(),fadeIn() effect in jquery. So if you want do it from jquery you need to remove those lines. But if you want do thing in css. remove jquery and keep those lines.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i just don't think it's a good way to solve problem. Having different divs for each picture. Thankfully you told, what you wanted to do. So i can see why you were creating different container divs for each photo. To make jquery work.

I have done it without using many divs. And simple jquery.

**Preview :**http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/jkhz5/4/embedded/result/ **UPDATED**

this is the whole code:::::

```
$("#main div").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),x=.2;
    $this.css({opacity:x});
    $this.hover(function(){$this.stop().animate({opacity: 1});},
                function(){$this.stop().animate({opacity: x});});
});
```

**Code Here :**http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/jkhz5/4/ **UPDATED**

Comment: That is nice but I think there is a problem if the images need to be posted dinamicaly using php or something similar. Should be quite hard to insert css instead of html.

Comment: changing css is complex and requires regex. But you can insert img tags inside the divs. And remove all from css, which is just a background.

Comment: jsfiddle is out, but i was able to do what you were asking..img tags inside main instead of divs